# If $A$ and $I$ are $k$-algebras, what is a '$k$-linear derivation $A \to I$?'

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For context this is from Hartshorne's exercise II.8.6. The situation is this: $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field and we have an exact sequence of $k$-algebras $$0 \to I \to B' \to B \to 0$$ and a homomorphism $f: A \to B$. Here $I \subseteq B'$ is an ideal satisfying $I^2 = 0$ where $B'$ is another $k$-algebra.

The claim in the book is that if $g, g': A \to B'$ are two lifts of $f$, then $\theta = g - g': A \to I$ is a $k$-linear derivation of $A$ into $I$.

What does this mean exactly?

If $I$ was an $A$ module this would mean that $\theta(xy) = x\theta(y) + y\theta(x)$. However I don't see how $I$ is canonically an $A$-module. You could take $g$ or $g'$ to define the $A$-module structure and it can be shown that $$\theta(xy) = g(x) \theta(y) + g'(y)\theta(x)$$ but I don't think this is what we want, as it seems to use two separate $A$-module structures.

Is there a canonical way to view $I$ as a an $A$-module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually define the $A$-module structure with $g$ or $g'$ and the leibniz rule will make sense, since $g(x) \theta(y) = g'(x) \theta(y)$. This fact follows from the fact that $I^2 = 0$. After all, $$g(x) \theta(y) - g'(x) \theta(y) = \theta(x) \theta(y) = 0$$ since $\theta(x) \theta(y) \in I^2$.

Sorry to answer my own question so quickly - I couldn't find a similar one online so I thought I shouldn't delete it.